# Is \u65549 a valid Java identifier?

Tags: java, identifier

I have these statements:

```
int \u65549 = 9;
System.out.println(\u65549);
```

This compiles perfectly. And outputs

```
9
```

**But :**

```
System.out.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(\u65549));
```

outputs

```
false
```

---

I did some research on this topic. I read the documentation, and it says:

> This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the `isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` method.

Then I did this:

```
int x = \u65549;
System.out.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(x));
```

But even this prints:

```
false
```

So, does this mean, that Java is confused over `\u65549` being an identifier?

Comment: @bcsb1001 You dropped the `int \u65549` declaration in both snippets, and that's why you couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: The accepted answer forgot to mentioned your 3rd example. Actually `int \u65549 = 9(you forgot to mention this must appear on top); int X = \u65549; Sop(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(x));` is same like `int A  = 9; int X = A; Sop(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(X));`, that's means same result as 2nd example `int A  = 9; Sop(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(A));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int \u65549 = 9;
System.out.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(\u65549));
```

Here, `\u65549` is the name of a variable, that also happens to contain the value `9`. It should (and does) do the same as if you wrote:

```
System.out.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(9));
```

which prints `false`, since you can't have a Java identifier starting with a whitespace character (`\u0009` is the codepoint for HORIZONTAL TAB, `'\t'`).

Comment: You did see my now-deleted comment in the notifications, didn't you? :) I made an obvious error in my thinking that I soon corrected, but the good thing is I helped make your post even more clear. **Edit:** I just checked the revision history and it seems that you happened to make the same mistake at first. Glad I'm not alone :)

Answer (score 2):

`\u65549` is interpreted as the unicode character `\u6554` , followed by the character `9`.

This is a valid syntax in a `String` .

Other than that, `\u65549` is not a valid unicode identifier.
A String only takes the valid part (`4` characters in the hexadecimal range) when it encounters a unicode prefix (`\u`), so it takes only the valid identifier part, and obtains a valid character .

Comment: Then why do those methods return false?

Comment: What does `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(\u6554)` print?

Comment: @AndyTurner It does not compile. The error says: "Cannot find symbol, varaiable <square>" (It actually draws a square.)

Comment: The `\uxxxx` syntax is valid as part of source anywhere, not just in a `String`.